Zsh: How to prevent multiple commands pasted together from being saved in history?
I have a Python script that helps us log into AWS CLI regardless of the operating system. On Linux, this script generates the following output:
set +o history
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=secret_value
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=very_secret_value
set -o history

When an operator copies and pastes these commands into a shell, the access key and secret key are not saved in the shell history due to the set +o history and set -o history commands.
However, when running the same script on macOS, this doesn’t work as expected. Instead, all the commands are saved as a single history entry with \n between the lines.
I wanted to ask if there's a solution to my problem.
What I’ve tried so far:

Using setopt HIST_NO_STORE to disable history for specific commands.
Using HIST_IGNORE_SPACE to avoid saving commands that start with a space.
Using fc -R with the here-string method (fc -R <<< $'command').
Prefixing commands with spaces when pasted, one at a time.

I want to prevent multiple commands (when pasted into the terminal) from being saved in the history on macOS. Ideally, I want each command to be treated as separate history entries.

Have you considered implementing the Python script as a passthru, so instead of writing shell commands as output, it sets the environment variables and then executes an arbitrary subprocess? That way you sidestep/moot the entire problem.

(os.execvp(sys.argv[1], *sys.argv[1:]) does most of the work; if someone wants an interactive shell with the script set, they can run yourscript bash -l or yourscript zsh -l as appropriate, or they can run an individual command that needs those variables as yourscript thing-that-needs-creds ...)

What version of zsh is used on macOS? I get set: no such option: history with zsh 5.9.

set -o is specifically a bash command. Some Macs still use bash (I do), but zsh has a different command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692913/temporarily-disable-history-in-zsh .   Why don't you create a file, have the operator do . runme, and have the file delete itself?
